# Marshalling an MFC CArray to C# through P/Invoke

Tags: c#, .net, mfc, pinvoke, marshalling

I am attempting to write a C# class (2010) that allows the usage of functions contained in a legacy C++ dll.  The functions are exported using __stdcall, and have varying sets of parameters.  I have no issue dealing with strings and other primatives, and am able to invoke these functions without issue.

The problem is that a few of the functions contain a CArray & reference as a parameter.  I cannot figure out how to marshal this datatype, or if it's even possible.

I can't change the legacy DLL code, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

To deal with this correctly, you can make a wrapper DLL (using the same MFC/C++ runtime version as what you want to call into, and make sure accepts the same array in the form of, say, a traditional pointer to a native C++ array.

This wrapper DLL can be called into from C#.

You could try with a more recent MFC version (and use C++/CLI for the marshalling), but then the new `CArray` could be binary incompatible with what to legacy library expects.

Comment: Could you show me a code example, or possibly point me to a resource that explains how to construct a wrapper class? I have never ventured into this territory before.  Thanks!

Comment: What MFC version was used to develop the legacy C++ dll? The wrapper needs to be that same version.

Comment: It's MFC90.  I have searched around for code examples, and all I can find are some class wrappers where the native code project is included as part of the solution.  Such is not the case here.  Here, I have a static DLL, exporting functions (not a class). I get the gist of what to do - basically call the  function with C++ and export the result using a managed datatype.  Problem is that I cannot figure out how to set the project up to start!

Comment: Oh, I have access to the header files and the .lib's.  It's not a COM DLL.

Comment: Oh, it should be easy then. Just take it one step at a time. I'm assuming mfc has dll linkage. First make a new dll in vs 2008 with mfc and .net enabled in the project settings. These are standard wizard options. Next link it to your legacy dll. Just add a function (unmanaged c++) that makes an empty CArray and calls your native code. if you get this to link youre ready to add a managed c++ class, with one static fn with no parameters. Check in the debugger you actually get there when called from .net. Dont worry about mixing 3.5/4.0, thats an issue for later. Report here for more instruction.

Comment: Thank you very much - I got it working to a point (all the linkages work just fine). But, I have encountered another issue. The function prototype in the legacy DLL (which I cannot change) looks like this:

Comment: BOOL WINAPI TheFunction(CArray<struct_Charbuffer, struct_Charbuffer> & output).  So, I declare a CArray and try to pass it to the function, I get a compile time error "Cannot convert parameter 1 from CArray<TYPE,ARG_TYPE> to CArray<TYPE, ARG_TYPE> &  I have tried everything from pinning the pointer to every conceivable combination of references/dereferences etc... and I just can't seem to find anything that works.  BTW, once I get the CArray, the goal is to pack it into a generic list and expose to C#.

Comment: How do you declare the CArray variable in your calling code? It should be CArray<struct_Charbuffer, struct_Charbuffer>, not CArray<struct_Charbuffer>.

Comment: I am declaring it:  CArray<struct_Charbuffer, struct_Charbuffer> myArray;

Comment: And passing it as - TheCFunction( myArray );  In the function prototype, myArray is a reference.  I do this all the time actually with CStrings, and have never encountered a problem.

Comment: OK. That's one issue out of the way. This is getting quite mysterious. If you write a function prototype (say `BOOL WINAPI TheTestFunction(CArray<struct_Charbuffer, struct_Charbuffer> & output);`, immediately above the function where you try to invoke this function, and try to call TheTestFunction, do you get the same error?

Comment: I actually get two errors:  One is an unresolved token, the other is an unresolved external symbol.  Now, if I move the prototype out of the function, to the root of the class, I get this error:

Comment: "None of the two overloads could convert all argument types".  The function is not overloaded, there is only a single prototype.  Doesn't seem to affect anything if I use the extern keyword or not, either.

Comment: "to the root of the class" - I meant to say root of the namespace

Comment: I think the compiler sees the test function, and the original prototype as two different overloads. Do they have the same name? The prototype is best defined outside any function/namespace, but otherwise as close as possible to the calling code to ensure struct_Charbuffer is not redefined by some obscure header file in the meantime.

Comment: I think I am quite close to the limit as how far I can help you remotely with this.